# B+ Tree leaf node size

Tags: c, database

[image]

In this picture, explaining that node size n is 4 (n = 4)
but I wonder that which one is node or pointer 
I think that Brandt, Califieri, Crick 's section is node but that section size is only 3... and between that section is pointer ( I think..)

so. I really want to know 'n = 4' exactly mean and how select n's size 
and this picture's mean...

thx..... ^^..;;

Comment: Nowhere is _this picture_ _explaining that node size n is 4_; you'd have to state wherefrom you got this information.

Answer (score 0):

As per the image , i think node is a row of the table containing 4 columns . The so named leaf node in image here , is some other structure , pointer of whose type can point to a node(row) of the given database.

---

Probably the leaf node is an array of 3 leaf node pointers , each component of which has 2 fields. One for pointer , and other for a string like "Brandit".

---

Or it may be a node with 7 fields , three of which are data fields and 4 are pointers to a node(row) of a database.

---